# does newfixedthreadpool create a blockignqueue internally

Tags: blockingqueue

When i use Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10), does the framework internally create a blockingqueue? Is there a way to supply my own queue while creating the thread pool? It is not clear to me from the oracle docs:[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29)

Comment: you may need more tags, are you talking about java? maybe it would be more visible to java people if you tagged it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, as found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newFixedThreadPool%28int%29).

Usually you do want a blocking queue, as the purpose of the queue is to hold on to jobs to prevent overwhelming `Executor`.  You could implement your own `Executor` + `ExecutorService` and use your custom queue in there, or, you could use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with your impl, similar to this:

```
88     public static ExecutorService More ...newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
89         return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
90                                       0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
91                                       new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
92     }
```

If the queue isn't blocking, then you'll start rejecting tasks, as mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).